# What does "within 12 months of expiry date" mean

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english

To upgrade a CPCS card from red to blue one of the items on the list states this, does it mean i have to wait till the red card only has 12 months left on it (red card is valid for two years) just trying to clarify that i understand what is being stated.

Comment: What is the complete wording?

Comment: (Too bad there's no [web site](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&q=cpcs+card&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDlZfMyovcAhWh5YMKHZqODdIQ7xYIJigA&biw=1122&bih=525) that covers this topic.)

Comment: Related to: [Interpret the phrase “within a month of the first Sunday in June”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447899/interpret-the-phrase-within-a-month-of-the-first-sunday-in-june/)

Answer (score 2):

It most likely means that you can upgrade from red to blue until 12 months *after* the red card expires.

I don't think there's a general rule that addresses whether "within  of " means before, after, or both. The context and logic of the situation usually determines which one is most likely.

So unless there's some reason why there should be a waiting period before you can upgrade, it's unlikely to mean "until there's 12 months left".

On the other hand, people don't immediately lose their competence the moment the red card expires. So if it has only expired recently, it's reasonable to allow them to apply for the upgraded card, rather than make them get the red card again first.